# How to specify string parameters in C# using webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hello I recently used a weather asmx web service here is the link as well http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx?op=GetWeather , im wondering though how can I only show off what I need.
this is the result I get:

> Berlin-Tegel, Germany (EDDT) 52-34N 013-19E 37M May 03, 2013 - 04:50
>   PM EDT / 2013.05.03 2050 UTC from the NNE (030 degrees) at 3 MPH (3
>   KT):0 greater than 7 mile(s):0 51 F (11 C) 33 F (1 C) 50% 30.03 in. Hg
>   (1017 hPa) Success

My code(one line): `Label1.Text = ws.GetWeather("Berlin", "Germany");`

as you can see above the webservice provides the weather and other details that I really not interested to show in my page thus im wondering how can I only show the details I need

Comment: What exactly is the question here?

Comment: What exactly is it that you are trying to do here?  And how is this related to a string parameter in a web service?

Comment: firstly sorry for not making the point so clear, as you can see above the webservice provides the weather and other details that I really not interested to show in my page thus im wondering how can I only show the details I need

Comment: @villecoder - the result from calling `ws.GetWeather()` is a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not getting back the result in your question. You are getting back the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<CurrentWeather>
  <Location>Berlin-Tegel, Germany (EDDT) 52-34N 013-19E 37M</Location>
  <Time>May 03, 2013 - 04:50 PM EDT / 2013.05.03 2050 UTC</Time>
  <Wind> from the NNE (030 degrees) at 3 MPH (3 KT):0</Wind>
  <Visibility> greater than 7 mile(s):0</Visibility>
  <Temperature> 51 F (11 C)</Temperature>
  <DewPoint> 33 F (1 C)</DewPoint>
  <RelativeHumidity> 50%</RelativeHumidity>
  <Pressure> 30.03 in. Hg (1017 hPa)</Pressure>
  <Status>Success</Status>
</CurrentWeather>
```

The individual items in the xml will allow you to display only the things you need

Comment: how can I display the details I need?

Comment: @Oneill parse the xml and take out the part you need.

Comment: you need to learn about xml. search for 'xml c# tutorial' or start by looking at the `XmlDocument` class. The breadth of the answer to the question in your comment is too large and too general for stack overflow.